# Are iterators from a concurrent hash map safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, folly

I am currently using [Facebook's concurrent hash map](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/concurrency/ConcurrentHashMap.h) and I am wondering if something like this would be possible:

```
folly::ConcurrentHashMap<std::string, some_class> m;

// add some elements

const auto it = m.find("a");

// during this time, another thread removes the "a" element

if (it != m.end())
    it->second.something(); // it is now an invalid iterator
```

After reading through the source of the hash map, I came across this:

> Iterators hold hazard pointers to the returned elements.  Elements can only be accessed while Iterators are still valid!

This is pretty unsettling and it feels like using any returned iterators are unsafe, is this so?

Comment: Any use? There are safe ways to use iterators. Obviously if you change or delete the elements they point to before using them then you're going to be on dodgy ground.

Comment: I think using anything in the folly namespace is ... well, folly ^_^

Comment: @Galik Well if you can't delete or change elements while reading them, what is the point of a concurrent hash map at all?

Comment: @UKMonkey The folly is pretty clearly "well, std doesn't do what we want.  Lets build ourself a replacement for std that does what we want.  What could go wrong?"  Either that, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folly

Comment: @Yakk or even https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/folly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The returned iterators are safe to use; however, the iterator object must be alive for the dereferenced value to be safe to access.

The 'hazard pointer' keeps the referenced value alive until the iterator is destructed.

`operator[]` and `at()` return the actual value for the given key, and so can't return a proxy object containing the hazard pointer. To ensure that they never return a reference to a dead object they instead return a copy of the value.

Whether you use iterators, or `operator[]`/`at()`, you will be operating on the value for the key at the time that you accessed the data, rather than the latest value for the given key.